# Call vared and complete files from a different directory

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, cd-command

I have the following zsh function which lets me edit symbolic links using the `vared` ZLE builtin.

```
function lned {
  emulate zsh
  setopt err_return extended_glob local_options local_traps
  local -a data
  link_path=${1%%/##}
  zstat -A data -L +link $link_path
  target=$data[1]
  if [[ -z $target ]]; then
    print -rl 1>&2 "$link_path: not a symbolic link"
    return 2
  fi
  vared -p "${(q)1} -> " target
  if [[ -n $target && "$target" != "$data[1]" ]]; then
    # We can't use 'ln -sf' if $link_path is a symlink to a directory, so remove
    # it manually first.
    # Check that this is still a symlink, in case the file was changed while we
    # were editing (this leaves only a very small time interval where we might
    # remove a non-symlink).
    rm -- $link_path(@)
    ln -s -- $target $link_path
  fi
}
```

This is nice, but when I'm editing a relative symbolic link in a directory other than the current one, the file name completions are relative to the wrong directory. I want to fix that.

I could run `pushd -- $link_path:h/` before calling `vared` and `popd` afterwards. However, this would not restore the current directory if the user interrupted the shell by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> at the wrong moment. This can be solved by setting traps exactly right, and maybe using `cd` rather than `pushd`, which is probably useful also to avoid having to detect whether the link is in the current directory (in which case `pushd` wouldn't push anything).

I'd like to minimize the disruption caused by the directory change, which means also locally turning off `chpwd`, restoring `OLDPWD`, and perhaps more which I'm not thinking of. Also, if I have no permission to `cd` back into the current directory, I'd be in a lurch — this is a very rare case but I'd prefer to support it.

It would be simpler if I could just set things up so that **files are completed relative to a different directory during the `vared` call**. How can I do that? If this is impossible, what's the best way to minimize the impact of a temporary directory change?

Comment: You can define your own completion with vared with `compdef myfunction -vared-`. See http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg01187.html for an example.

Comment: Gilles, I tried your function and completion works fine for me inside it. Can you give a test case for which it fails?

Comment: @MarlonRichert Completion is relative to the current directory instead of being relative to the directory containing the symlink. To reproduce: `ln -s tmq link; mkdir tmp; cd tmp; lned ../link` then press BackSpace and Tab. Completion offers nothing (because you're in an empty directory), but `tmp` is a valid target for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `lned`, add the following before calling `vared`:

```bsh
local curcontext=lned:::
```

Put the following in a file called `_lned` in your `$fpath`:

```bsh
#autoload
_files -W $link_path:h/
```

Then add this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:lned:*' completer _lned
```

Now it works as expected.