# Complete a command fully relative to a different directory

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, cd-command, pwd

I have a function to run a single command in a different category. `cd1 SOMEDIR MYCOMMAND ARG…` is equivalent to `(cd SOMEDIR && MYCOMMAND ARG…)`, with two advantages. It's slightly easier to type (and when you're a command line junkie, every key press matters), and  (mostly), it lets me do completion relative to `SOMEDIR`.

That is, it lets me define a completion function for `cd1`. **How do I arrange to complete relative to `SOMEDIR`?**

The following methods don't work without modification:

- Making ad hoc calls to `_files` with a modified argument for the arguments of the command is no good here (unlike [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120649/call-vared-and-complete-files-from-a-different-directory)) because I want all the usual context-sensitive completion to apply.
- `(cd $words[2] && shift 2 words && ((CURRENT-=2)) && _normal)` would do the right thing if completion worked in a subshell, but it doesn't.
- `cd $words[2] && shift 2 words && ((CURRENT-=2)) && _normal; cd $OLDPWD` works in nominal cases but breaks and leaves me in `SOMEDIR` in some cases, such as if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel a completion that takes too long.

---

Here's the definition of `cd1`. It supports aliases and expands wildcards relative to the target directory (on the other hand, command substitutions and the like will still run in the original directory).

```
cd1_glob () {
  if (($# <= 1)); then
    cd -- "$1"
  elif (($+aliases[$2])); then
    ( cd -- $1 && eval $2 '$~@[3,$#]' )
  else
    ( cd -- $1 && $~@[2,$#] )
  fi
}
alias cd1='noglob cd1_glob'
```

(I don't call this function `cd`. If you do, change the calls to `cd` inside the functions to `builtin cd`.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have so far. It isn't perfect, but it does:

- complete relative to the target directory;
- fail silently if the target directory doesn't exist;
- skip `chpwd` and `chpwd_functions` and I think restore them correctly;
- restore the current directory if the completio is cancelled.

It looks complex and fragile so I'm not completely confident about corner cases. Known issues:

- Completion doesn't always add a suffix character (such as a space, or `/` for a directory. For example `cd1 / echo /bi`<kbd>Tab</kbd> inserts `n/` but `cd1 / echo bi`<kbd>Tab</kbd>  only inserts `n` (whereas `echo bi`<kbd>Tab</kbd> does insert `n/`).
- If the original directory is renamed during the completion operation, the shell returns to the new directory with the old name, not to the old directory with the new name.

```sh
#compdef cd1 cd1_glob
# cd for one command

_cd1_in () {
  setopt local_options local_traps
  # Cleanup:
  # * Restore the old directory. We do this only if cd succeeded beause
  #   the restoration can do the wrong thing in corner cases (renamed
  #   directory).
  # * Restore the chpwd hook function and the hook array.
  trap 'if ((_cd1_cd_succeeded)); then cd $OLDPWD; fi
        if [[ -n $_cd1_chpwd_function ]]; then
          functions[chpwd]=$_cd1_chpwd_function
        fi
       ' EXIT INT
  builtin cd $words[2] 2>/dev/null || { _cd1_cd_succeeded=0; return 1; }
  shift 2 words; ((CURRENT -= 2))
  _normal
}

_cd1 () {
  if ((CURRENT > 2)); then
    setopt local_options no_auto_pushd unset
    local _cd1_cd_succeeded=1
    # Save the current directory and the chpwd hook. They will be restored
    # by the exit trap in _cd1_in.
    local _cd1_chpwd_function=$functions[chpwd]
    # Save the current directory in $OLDPWD. _cd_in will call cd, which would
    # generally call cd
    local OLDPWD=$PWD
    # Turn off the chpwd hook function and the associated hook array.
    local chpwd_functions=
    unset -f chpwd 2>/dev/null
    # Call a separate function to do the work. Its exit trap will take care
    # of cleanup. The reason to have a separate function is so that the
    # local variables defined here can be used in the exit trap.
    _cd1_in
  else
    _dirs
  fi
}

_cd1 "$@"
```