# How to add an alias for 'git add **/'

Tags: bash, zsh, git, alias

I can't seem to add an alias for `git add **/`

I think those two asterisks is causing an issue, or it could be that forward slash. How do I solve this?

So far I have tried

```
alias ga='git add **/'
```

When I run the above alias in my terminal, I issue this command `ga somename.java` which would be an equivalent if alias was not there would be `git add **/somename.java`.

I have also tried adding more asterisks, slashes, dollar sign followed by a quote, etc.

Comment: What command do you want to run exactly? Do you want `ga` to run `git add **/` or are you expecting it to take arguments so that if you run `ga foo bar` it will actually execute `git add **/foo` and `git add **/bar`?

Comment: `ga foo` should expand to `git add **/foo`

Comment: I will never run `ga foo bar`. It seems Giles also went on to the same tangent. I don't even know what `ga foo bar is`. I will just run `ga foo`. That's it. And if needed I will run it multiple times replacing foo with whatever. And I will always run it from the root of the project. In the end, I just want to stage changes in foo file in git. foo has a long directory stucture prepended to it. I want to avoid typing. So `git add **/foo` is a shortcut to add a particular file without copying the whole directory path prepended to it. I want to create an alias that would even shorten this part.

Comment: If you'd be doing `ga file1 file2`, that's `ga foo bar` for purposes of the above. You mean to tell us you run a separate `git add` for every single file?

Comment: I would recommend not doing so. Because you might have `*.class` files, `*~` backup files from your editor, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh good to know. that's makes it a little easier for me to stage files. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ga somename.java` is short for `git add **/ somename.java`. The first argument to the alias is not concatenated to the last word inside the alias. You can think of it this way: the space that you type after `ga` is not removed.

To do anything more complex than give a command an alternate name or pass arguments to a command, use a function instead of an alias.

Here's a zsh version which is pretty versatile.

```
function ga {
  git add **/$^~@(.N)
}
alias ga='noglob ga'
```

Here's how it works for `ga foo* bar`:

1. The alias `ga` expands to `noglob ga`.
2. Thanks to the [`noglob` precommand modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-noglob), `noglob ga foo* bar` does not expand the wildcard in `foo*`, and instead passes `foo*` literally as an argument to `ga`.
3. Since `ga` (the one in `noglob ga …`) isn't the first word in the command, it is not looked up as an alias, and therefore it refers to the function, which is called with the arguments `foo*` and `bar`.
4. `$^~@` uses the [`${^spec}` and `${~spec}` parameter expansion forms](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). The modifier `^` causes `**/` to be prepended to each element of the array `$@`, resulting in `**/foo*` and `**/bar`. Without this modifier, `**/$@` would expand to `**/foo*` and `bar`.
5. `$~@` causes the wildcard characters in the arguments to be expanded now. This way, the pattern `foo*` is not expanded by itself: what's expanded is `**/foo*`, so this matches things like `sub/dir/foobar`.
6. The `.` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) causes only regular files to be matched. Make it `-.` to also match symbolic links to regular files, or `@.` to match all symbolic links in addition to regular files.
7. The `N` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) causes patterns that match nothing to be omitted. Don't put `(N)` if you prefer to have an error if one of the patterns doesn't match anything.

About the only nice thing that's missing here is completion, which is [doable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120649/call-vared-and-complete-files-from-a-different-directory) but I think not worth the trouble here.

In bash, you can't have it as nice. There's no way to prevent wildcards from being expanded immediately, so `ga foo*` will be equivalent to `ga foo1 foo2` if the directory content is

```
.git …
foo1
foo2
subdir
subdir/foobar
```

which will miss `subdir/foobar`.

In bash, since you need to quote wildcards in arguments, you might as well rely on Git's own pattern matching in a [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pathspec). Note in particular that `*` matches directory separators, i.e. it has the shell `**` behavior built in.

```
function ga {
  local x
  for x in "$@"; do
    git add "*/$x"
  done
}
ga 'foo*' bar
```

On a final note, if you keep your `.gitignore` up-to-date and commit often, you'll rarely need anything other than `git add .`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on shell extglobs at all, you can tell `find` to do a recursive search and run `git add` for you.

```
ga() {
  local -a find_args
  local arg

  for arg in "$@"; do
    find_args+=( -o -name "$arg" )
  done

  find . '(' -false "${find_args[@]}" ')' -exec git add -- {} +
}
```